# Regarding permutations and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be a permutation and $T_{\sigma} $ the matrix we obtain from $I$ by appling $\sigma$ on the raws of $I$ (I.e $\sigma$ acts on the rows of $I$) . Then:

$\det(T_{\sigma}) = sgn(\sigma) $
and  $T_{\sigma} T_{\tau} =T_{\sigma\circ \tau}$, for all $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$.

How do we see this? What Can we use here?

For the second part, we know that $sgn(\sigma\circ \tau)=sgn(\sigma) sgn(\tau) $ so there is an equality between the det.

Comment: use the Leibniz definition of the determinant. For the second part just hit the matrix with a standard vector i.e., $(0,\cdots ,1,\cdots ,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

The action of $T_{\sigma}$ is to permute the rows of $I$.  From elementary rows operations, we know that swapping the order of two rows multiplies the determinant by $-1$.  By definition, and odd permutation can always be factored into an odd number of transpositions.  Hence, determinant will be multiplied by $(-1)^{2n-1} = -1 = \text{sgn}({\sigma})$.  Same idea for even permutations.

For the second part, if we compose two permutations, it is the same as applying one first, and then the other, hence the expression $T_{\sigma}T_{\tau}$.

Comment: Thanks, why it is 2n-1?  The second part looks trivial but how to explain it more formally?

Comment: I was just trying to represent an arbitrary odd number. $n$ has nothing to do with the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's useful to think with linear morphisms. Let $\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n$ and $f_\sigma : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be the linear map defined by $f_\sigma(e_i) = e_{\sigma(i)}$ where $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ is the canonical base of $\mathbb R^n$. Then the matrix associated to $f_\sigma$ is $T_{\sigma}$ and you can show that for $\tau \in \mathfrak S_n$, we have $f_\sigma \circ f_\tau = f_{\sigma \circ \tau}$ (this is almost by definition) and the same relation will be true for their matrices.

Now recall that every permutation in $\mathfrak S_n$ is a composition of transpositions, that the signature of a permutation is a group homomorphism $\text{sgn} : \mathfrak S_n \to \big(\{-1,1\}, \times\big)$ and that the determinant is also a group homomorphism $\det : \text{End}(\mathbb R^n) \to \big( \mathbb R, \times \big)$. It is sufficient by what whe have shown above to prove that $\det(f_{\tau}) = \text{sgn}(\tau) = -1$ for all transpositions $\tau \in \mathfrak S_n$. But now this is obvious since the determinant is antisymmetric.

Comment: By the way, you have shown that you have a (faithful) group representation $\mathfrak S_n \to GL_n(\mathbb R)$ and the signature is "the same thing" (under this faithful representation) as the determinant.